# Auth0 seed project error

Tags: auth0

I am new to Auth0 and I thought I start by downloading the seed project to examine it.  I am using .NET Core.  I downloaded the project, but when I ran it I get an error:

**SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:...**

This happened after I tried logging in and during the execution of the callback (http://localhost:5000/signin-auth0)

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You should provide more information. What parts of the sample projects you modified? The error points to a mismatch in the keys being used to validate a JWT token which could be caused by not updating the necessary configuration. Also providing a link to the sample projects makes it easier for other to see what the code is doing.

Comment: I did not modify anything.  The project came with the information pre-populated with my credentials.  This is the project I am referring to:  https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnet-owin-mvc-sample

Comment: You mention that you're using .NET Core; any reason for not following https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnetcore-sample instead of the OWIN sample? If you do follow the ASP .NET Core sample linked and get similar issues, also include the exception stacktrace in the question.

Comment: You are right :)  I sent you the wrong link.  I actually receive a response on the Auth0 forum.  I will post it as an answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from the Auth0 forum (thank you Nicolas Sabena)that solved the problem:

> The .Net Core seed projects are meant to work with the RS256 algorithm by default.
>   To change the algorithm, go to Clients | {Your client} | Settings, then click on the Show advanced settings link, and select the OAuth tab. In the JsonWebToken Signature Algorithm dropdown, select RS256.

After switching to RS256, everything worked.